# Will the call to SecTrustCreateWithCertificates cause a memory leak in Alamofire?

Tags: alamofire

In Alamofire,

```
extension AlamofireExtension where ExtendedType == SecCertificate {
    public var publicKey: SecKey? {
        let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()
        var trust: SecTrust?
        let trustCreationStatus = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(type, policy, &trust)

        guard let createdTrust = trust, trustCreationStatus == errSecSuccess else { return nil }

        return SecTrustCopyPublicKey(createdTrust)
    }
}
```

SecTrustCreateWithCertificates call create a trust object. According to Apple's official documentation:

> **trust**
> On return, points to the newly created trust management object.
> Call the CFRelease function to release this object when you are
> finished with it.

The trust object should be released by calling the CFRelease function (like this: `CFRelease(createdTrust)`)，but it is not called here.
Will there be a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreFoundation objects are automatically memory managed when used from Swift.